# How to add values from a for loop into dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with longitudes and latitudes which are generated using this function:

```
for i in df['address']:
    lat=locator.geocode(f'{i}')
    #print(lat.latitude) this works
    df['latitudes'].lat.latitude #this does not work!
```

It prints out all latitudes correctly, however when I tried to add these values into a dataframe column df['latitudes'], I get an error:  `'Series' object has no attribute 'lat'`

How do I fix this?

Comment: What happens when you set `df['latitudes'] = lat.latitude`?

Comment: @David_G it states this error: 'float' object has no attribute 'latitude' :(

Comment: Can you add lat.latitude into a list, then add it as a new column into the df. To start with, can you initialise `temp=[]` outside of the loop, then add the `lat.latitude` values into `temp` with `temp[i]=lat.latitude`.
(Disclaimer: I'm no python expert!)

Comment: Please provide the entire error output, as well as a [mcve]. What do you understand from that error message?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that this error basically implies that geocoder was NOT able to find the coordinates of a particular address. I therefore added a try: except: statement and it then worked wonderfully by skipping the "bad" address.

```
for i in df['address']:
    try:
        lat=locator.geocode(f'{i}').latitude
        df['latitude']=lat
    except: print('address not found or invalid!')
```

Comment: _I found out that this error basically implies that geocoder was NOT able to find the coordinates of a particular address._ That's not what the error you posted seems to indicate at all, though, no?